# 64 bit TWAIN scanner driver not detected when running through Citrix Receiver

Tags: citrix, citrix-receiver

We have created a 64 bit .NET application that has the possibility to scan documents. Before scanning, it shows the list of (TWAIN compatible) scanners attached to the machine.

When the 64-bit TWAIN driver for the scanner is installed on the machine, the scanner is detected by our application when running in normal mode (so not over Citrix). But on the same client machine, when the application is running over Citrix, then the scanner is NOT detected. Before we upgraded our application from 32 to 64 bit and using 32 bit scanner drivers we didn't have this problem.

We did try to configure some related Citrix policies, such as:

- "Client TWAIN device redirection" -> Allowed
- "Client USB device redirection" -> Allowed
- "Client USB Plug and Play device redirection" -> Allowed

We're using Citrix 7 1912 LTSR and Citrix Receiver v 4.12.0.18020. I'm wondering if 64-bit scanner drivers are supported, or if this is rather a configuration problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Citrix client instaled on the PC itself a 64-bit application? That is required in order to use 64-bit drivers.

Comment: @Tonny: Thank you for your suggestion! That makes sense indeed. We are currently using a 32 bit Citrix Receiver. However, so far we weren't able to find a 64 bit version of that.

Comment: Citrix Receiver is old and no longer actively supported by Citrix. You will have to switch to the Citrix WorkSpace App I think (is backwards compatible). WorkSpace App appears to be 32/64 bit combined. Citrix doesn;t say so on their website, but when I check the install on my laptop it has 32 and 64 bit components.